# Python subprocess running out of order on Windows

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, concurrency, process

I'm running a python script on Windows.
I have a python script like this:

```
subprocess.call(1)

subprocess.Popen(2)

subprocess.call(3)
```

when I run the script, the results I get runs like this:

```
subprocess.call(3)

subprocess.call(1)

subprocess.Popen(2)
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Popen can easily be explained since it doesn't necessarily wait for terminate. It's harder to explain why call(3) finishes first without seeing more code. You might try `sys.stdout.flush()` between calls. Also are you waiting for your Popen(2) to finish?

Answer (score 0):

Each new process you create with `subprocess` spawns a new sub-process, hence its name. This means the commands will finish running at different times meaning you get the results in a different order.

It is not the same as calling a function in Python, where the function finishes running before the others are ran.

Comment: `call` should wait for finish though.

Comment: @doogabides Well, how could the processes finish at different times if `call` waits?

Comment: `subprocess.call` "Run the command described by args. Wait for command to complete, then return the returncode attribute" from docs. Version 2/3 same exact docstring.

Comment: @doogabides That is really strange then, because it is acting exactly contradictory to its docs.